# Converting c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++

1) My program runs fine in c++, im just trying to convert it to c#, Need help converting the ifstream part
c++ code:

```
ifstream data;
data.open("data.txt");
if (data.fail()) {
    cout << "Error opening file\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

So far this is what i got from research is to use filestream and streamreader
c# code: Just want to make sure its equivalent.

```
        if(!File.Exists(data))
        {
            Console.Write("{0} does not exist.", data);
            return 0;
        }
        FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(data, FileMode.Open, 
         FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fsIn))
```

2) Next part where im stuck on, is on the function where its suppose to get the data from the .txt file and store into an array (the data.txt file is added from solution of the project so no url to the file was required)(using visual studio)
c++ code:

void read_file(ifstream& fsIn, float h_temp[], int array_size, int& valid_entries_high, int& valid_entries_low, float l_temp[])
{

```
while (!data.eof()) // eof = end of file
{
    data >> h_temp[valid_entries_high];
    valid_entries_high++;

    data >> l_temp[valid_entries_low];
    valid_entries_low++;

    if (valid_entries_high + valid_entries_low == array_size) {
        cout << "Array's full,\n";
        break;
    }
}
    if (valid_entries_high == valid_entries_low)
    {
        cout << "file is valid" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    //check make sure theyre the same length
```

}

This is where im stuck on with my c#:
 public static void read_file(FileStream fsIn, float[] h_temp, int array_size, ref int valid_entries_high, ref int valid_entries_low, float[] l_temp)
        {

```
        while (!fsIn.EndofStream()) // eof = end of file
        {
            fsIn >> h_temp[valid_entries_high];
            valid_entries_high++;

            fsIn >> l_temp[valid_entries_low];
            valid_entries_low++;

            if (valid_entries_high + valid_entries_low == array_size)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Array's full,\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valid_entries_high == valid_entries_low)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("file is valid");
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

    }
```

converting that input << sign into c# and also why .EndofStream wont work? Im using sysmtem.io like the tutorial said but it says Filestream does not contain a definition for 'endofstream'. Also is ifstream& the same as FileStream ref?
Any advice will be greatly apperciated!

Comment: You don't program by "converting" code written in one language into a completely different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have no idea what your file format looks like but I'll make an assumption that you want to read each line into an array element...

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\Developer\TestFile.txt");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a specific format then you'd need to provide us with more detail, Bu I can recommend the FileHelpers library from GitHub as an ideal way to import delimited data if that's what you're looking for.

And yeah, like Neil Butterworth said coding in a new language exactly as you would in C++ isn't the way forward. .NET is a framework that does the majority of heavy lifting for you and in a very intuitive way. Don't try to re-write rudimentary code.  I wouldn't even be doing that in C++, I'd be using Boost or Qt and only go down to the low level for rare scenarios. 
Incidentally, before you start trying to write your own code to sort and query data structures in memory, learn about LINQ and spend the time you save doing more important things.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the great advice will look up up on LINQ,

Comment: But yes, you assumed correctly, so i wanted to read each line of data into an array element. Just to my defense, I was just using my c++ code as a pseudo code for my c# and had trouble expressing an instruction that in language x, but i do keep track to see which instruction is going into the memory call stack etc. Once again thanks again your code helped alot

Comment: I've added another answer showing how it's actually done internally in .NET just as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it manually the simplest way is the way it's done in the .NET framework:

```
String line; 
List<String> lines = new List<String>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        lines.Add(line);
```

If you wanted an array:

```
string[] linesArray = lines.ToArray();
```